# Draw an envelope for only selected features in many/Batch layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, geometry, vector-layer, qgsvectorlayer

I have about 1000 layers, I did select by attributes Batch files and select by one step features I need in all 1000 layers. Now I need to draw the envelope for those selected features in all 1000 layers in one step.

There is an option in a single layer process for draw envelope in selected features only by [image: minimum bounding geometry], but in the Batch files, I can not find this option, what can I do?

Comment: Merging the layers into one would be a workaround

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround, which divides your workflow into three-steps.

(1) Go back to your original layers, and start the Field Calculator. Add a new field using the expression you have used in the *Select by attributes*.

The new field can be anything, but let's assume we have just created `value` field with only `0` and `1`; and `1` represents the features you have selected.

[image]

(2) Run the **Minimum bounding geomtry** tool in the *Batch mode*.

Now you can use `value` field in the **Field (optional, see if features should be grouped by class)** and the tool will create Envelopes for both `selected (1)` and `un-selected (0)`.

[image]

(3) Apparently we need to remove envelopes for the `un-selected` features.

Start **Extract by attributes** tool. `value = 1` is the wanted features. Ignore `Extracted (un-matching)` column.

[image]

NB. You can use **Extract by attributes** tool (step 3) before **Minimum bounding geometry** tool (step 2). Perhaps it is faster than the above workflow.